# Apache vs Jetty with regard to Security

Tags: web-application, webserver, java, apache

I am trying to design the architecture of an app that will run on an AWS Linux AMI, inside of a Docker container.

The app will deal with sensitive financial data, so ***security is top priority***. The app is expected to handle a very heavy load, with tens of thousands of requests being sent to it per second.

If there is a significant security boost, then **security takes priority over speed**. The logic is simple: If I have a serious breach and lose the faith of my customers/investors, an extra 500ms in load time won't help me.

I already consulted with a security expert at a well-known company in San Francisco, and they recommended using [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

They advised that while there would be a performance drop from [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), the security gains were so significant that it was worth it. They also recommended Jetty over [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/). They said that Apache and Nginx were written in C, and as such, contained more security vulnerabilities than a server written in an interpreted language like Java.

They also advised me not to use a web server in languages like Python and Ruby, citing potential security flaws.

I then learned that **Google App Engine switched from Apache Tomcat to Jetty** for their web server/servlet container, and that strengthened the argument. [InfoQ article - Why Google Chose Jetty](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/08/google-chose-jetty)

So while there seemed to be a lot of strong arguments going for Jetty (security expert's suggestion, Google's choice), I wanted to open this discussion up to the **InfoSec** community on Stack Exchange.

In your opinion, which of the following is the most secure, if we ignore for a minute the app code that is written on top of it?

- Jetty
- Apache Tomcat
- Nginx
- Python/Ruby based Web Server
- Node.js Web Server
- others that I haven't mentioned

Comment: This all sounds valid, but I expect other factors in your app will affect security far more than choice of web server.

Comment: Let's start with the basics (choosing the most secure webserver on the market), and then we can move on to in-app security. Think about it, if you go nuts on encryption and auth, and then someone hacks your app via your version of Apache, you haven't achieved much, have you? So first choose a secure webserver, no?

Comment: "Apache and Nginx were written in C, and as such, contained more security vulnerabilities than a server written in an interpreted language like Java" -- while it *might* be true that Apache and Nginx have more vulnerabilities than Jetty (I have no idea about whether or not that is true), the argument "java is better than c in terms of security" is flawed: the JVM is *not* guaranteed to be bug-free and most JVMs are partially implemented in c/c++. It boils down to the quality of the code, it is merely easier to make mistakes in c/c++. So for Jetty, your next question is which JVM to choose ;)

Comment: "which technology would you choose" is a really subjective question. This might get closed as "opinion-based".

Comment: Jetty has had a recent vulnerability: https://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2015/2/25/jetleak-vulnerability-remote-leakage-of-shared-buffers-in-je.html Apache had many vulns in the past but a good record in the past 10 years. for security, choice of web server matters little

Comment: Apache *httpd* is written in C, but **Tomcat is Java**, except optionally the (pretty small) "native"/APR option for SSL/TLS. And even granting JVM (almost always) catches low-level flaws like buffer overrun and dangling pointer, in recent years most web vulnerabilities are at protocol and application levels like compression, header splitting, cookies, crypto, XSS, XSRF, SQL injection, etc, which don't depend on language as such, but often depend on server and/or framework which *implies* a language.

Comment: @schroeder, I updated the final question in the post. +dst, feel free to offer a suggestion to that one. More opinions are always helpful. Well, from the answers here, plus Google's choice, plus the security expert's suggestion, I'm going with Jetty atm.